# How to control execution time of a process and handle exception across classes in c#

Tags: c#, exception, execution-time, performance-measuring

I appreciate your support in below:

I have function getCode(processURL_) , that is complex function and has many function works in the underlying of it, and consume time, so I want to monitor the execution time and stop it if it exceeds certain threshold of 20 sec for example..

I figured out how to put threshold for the execution time of the process by using parallel monitoring process , but:

1- The required here is to fire parallel elapsed time calculation, using "monitoring process" that works in parallel along with the this complex process and measure the elapsed time <<=== this is done...........

2- And if it exceeds the threshold, it will Throw Exception for "Time is up" <<=== this is done...........

3- Now I cannot catch the thrown exception for time is up ?? as it is thrown by parallel process ( Tired both to be form the same class or another class )

it could be thrown to the system by the function _ProcessTimeMonitoring from the function class sucessfully, and kill the app, but I need to throw the exception by the function *ProcessTimeMonitoring and catch it in main class to kill function getCode(processURL*) using this exception trick  <<=====

, So please could anyone help for this exception handling across classes.

or anyway to break the main function if the parallel function time is up ??

Thanks in advance.

```
    public static Functions__V51 _functions = new Functions__V51();
    
        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t return Code = " + getCode(processURL_));
                    }
                    catch (Exception _functions.Time_is_Up)
                    {
                        throw;
                        // to catch thrown exception raised by Process Time Monitoring
                        Console.WriteLine(_functions.Time_is_Up.Message);
                        //throw;
                    }
            }

    public static string getCode(string _processURL_)
        {

            // 4-when the url is down the script should return the value 3.

            try
            {
                if (functions__.linkExists(_processURL_))
                {
                    stopWatch.Start();

                    _functions._ProcessTimeMonitoring_();

                    // do Asynchronous job here ...

                }
            }
            catch(exceptiopn ex)
            {

            }

        }
    
           //==============  Another class of functions
    
        class Functions__V51      
        {
            
            public Exception _Time_is_Up = new Exception("Time is UP, by the way");   
    
    
            public async void _ProcessTimeMonitoring()
            {
                _TimeisUp = false;
                try
                {
                    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    
                        while (stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 20000 && !_TimeisUp)
                        {
    
                           
    
                        }
    
                        // raising killer flag for the main process
                        stopWatch.Stop();
                        _TimeisUp = true; // global bool flag
    
                        Console.WriteLine("Process Time is Up !!!!!!!!");
    
    
                        throw _Time_is_Up;  // << this exception need to be caugh in main class to kill getCode function
    
                    });
    
                }
                catch (Exception _Time_is_Up)
                {    
                    //throw;
                }
                
            }    
          
         } // end of Class Functions
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed solution that worked for me but need enhancement

simply by using firing back and forth between the two functions until breaking the main function :0) .. as per below comments in the code.

```
public static Functions__V51 _functions = new Functions__V51();

    
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("return Code = " + getCode(processURL_));

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // to catch thrown exception raised by Process Time Monitoring
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    //throw;
                }
        }


public static string getCode(string _processURL_)
    {

        try
        {
            if (functions__.linkExists(_processURL_))
            {
                stopWatch.Start();

                // to be fired in parallel to measure the time and kill getCode function in case exceeded certain threshold
                _functions._ProcessTimeMonitoring();  


                // do Asynchronous job here ...
                // do Asynchronous job here ...  

                // webdriver was used in these Asynchronous jobs !! so I used it to raise the the exception which will affecr function getCode !!
                // simply by kill webdriver in function _ProcessTimeMonitoring_
                
                // do Asynchronous job here ...

            }
        }
        catch(exceptiopn ex)
        {

        }

    }



       //==============  Another class of functions

    class Functions__V51      
    {
        


    public async void _ProcessTimeMonitoring()
    {
        _TimeisUp = false;

        stopWatch.Start();


        try
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

                while (stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 20000 && !_TimeisUp)
                {

                }

                stopWatch.Stop();
                _TimeisUp = true;

                Console.WriteLine("Process Time is Up !!!!!!!!");

                throw new TimeoutException("Time is Up !!"); //

            });

        }
        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            // kill webdriver  *********

            _Driver_.Close();
            _Driver_.Dispose();
            _Driver_.Quit();

            //throw;
        }

    }
      
} // end of Class Functions
```